# Table inside JQuery-Tabs prevents HighCharts from being displayed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, highcharts, tabs, html-table

I have got the following code, where one Jquery tab displays a table, and the other tab displays a pie chart made using HighCharts.
If I remove the table in between the div tag, the pie chart shows up successfully, however once a table is included inside the div, the pie chart is not shown anymore. is there something wrong with my code or is that a known highcharts/jQuery issue?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#pie').highcharts({
            chart: { type:'pie' },
            title: { text: 'Test'},
            tooltip: {
                pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage}%</b>',
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.point.name +'</b>: '+ Math.round(this.percentage) +' %';
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: true,
                    dataLabels: false,
                    showInLegend: true
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Overall Attendance',
                data: [
                    ['Present Students',4],
                    ['Absent Students',4],
                    ['Late Students',5]
                ]
            }],
            colors: [
                '#132f55',
                '#eeeeee',
                '#7f95aa'
            ]
        });
    });
</script>

<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#registration" data-toggle="tab">Registration</a></li>
  <li><a href="#pie" data-toggle="tab">Pie Chart</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="registration">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_register_path(@register) %> |
    <%= link_to 'Back', registers_path %>

  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="pie" style="width:91%; height:400px; ">  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please take look at article about reason which can caused this issue http://docs.highcharts.com/#faq$jquery-ui-tab

Comment: That's not applicable to my code though, as all I'm doing is try to view a chart when there is a table int he other tab. If you remove the table and just insert text it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Please see the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rajeswari0709/CPUbW/12/)

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#registration">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#pie">Proin dolor</a></li>

  </ul>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="registration">
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
        <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
<div class="tab-pane" id="pie" style="width:91%; height:400px; ">  <div id="chart"></div>

</div>
```

You need to enclose the div properly.

Comment: Can you please share some more details of your HTML structure? It will be useful if you share as jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?
See demo here:
http://jsfiddle.net/visnupriya/qFwwf/

Code is here:

```
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
    <div id="container" style="width: 320px; height: 200px"></div>
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
  <table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Content for Tab 3</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the way I want it to be

Comment: Hmm strange, when i implement your code in my Rails app, it doesn't work. I'm also using Bootstrap by the way

Comment: try this sample demo using twitter boostrap - http://jsfiddle.net/visnupriya/zWjFV/1/